Can I use a smart switch with a normal switch?
I have 2 ceiling lights controlled by 2 switches. So each switch can turn on and off both lights simultaneously. I want to replace one of the switch with a smart wifi switch but not sure it it's possible or where the common wire is supposed to go.
My question is can they both work simultaneously? If so, then what should be the wiring configuration in the Smart switch and would I need to change wiring in my normal switch as well?
Currently in normal switch has L1 with common wire, L2 with live, and L3 with neutral.
Picture of my wiring:
Normal switch:

Smart Switch:


This is clearly not US/Canada. Rules, typical switch types, etc. vary considerably around the world. I suggest including your country or region as that may help others provide reliable answers.
